# How to parse local JSON file using gson And impliment room?

Tags: android, json

```
[
  {
    "": 0,
    "Gender": "Girl",
    "Meaning": "Idealistic",
    "Name": "A'adarshini",
    "Origin": "Hindi"
  },
  {
    "": 1,
    "Gender": "Girl",
    "Meaning": "Hope and need",
    "Name": "A'dab",
    "Origin": "Arabic"
  },
  {
    "": 2,
    "Gender": "Girl",
    "Meaning": "Visiting, returning, reward",
    "Name": "A'idah, aida",
    "Origin": "Arabic"
  }
]
```

I have this JSON file local on my Android studio I want to read it using Gson library and implement Room? how to achieve this?

I Am trying to get JSON String like this but getting errors

```
   String json;
    try {
        InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.names);
        if (is != null) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();

            Log.d(TAG, "readData: data recived" + json);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use below code.

```
 String jsonOutput; // Your json string
 Type listType = new TypeToken<List<RoomModel>>() {}.getType();
 ArrayList< RoomModel > rooms = new Gson().fromJson(jsonOutput, listType);


public class RoomModel
{
    public int ID,
    public String Gender;
    public String Meaning;
    public String Name;
    public String Origin;
}
```

Comment: I am having trouble getting the String JSON can you help me with this  ?

Comment: I am doing this

Comment: Can you please explain more what error you are getting, also you need to change this part to some meaningful thing "": 2, to let's say "id" : 2

Comment: I just wanted this JSON to parse and implement room and update the recyclerview with the names and when clicked the whole detail comes up

Comment: Can you check my repo what i am doing wrong in this  ? https://github.com/vivekpanchal/BabyApp

Comment: In your code you have parsed CSV Data and showed in adapter, what exactly do you want me to fix?

Comment: i don't get the data in the adapter the mainactivity no data is displayed in the UI

Comment: now i have used the csv file to read data and impliment room database would be really helpfull if you can see whats wrong with this